# VBA Macro - Save Copy of Active Workbook without opening the windows Explorer

Tags: vba, excel

I'm saving a Word Document in my Excel Macro, The User defines the Export Path with the SaveAs2() Function (Windows Explorer opens up etc.).

Now my Problem is that I want to save a copy of my Current Workbook to the same directory with the same Filename as the Word Document.
**BUT** everytime the User chooses the Export Path of the Word File, another Windows Explorer Window comes up and asks the User where to save the Excel File.

So how can i disable this second Windows Explorer Window?

I tried it like this:

```
Dim ExportPath As String
Dim ExcelExport As String

ExportPath = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(ActiveWorkbook.Names("AccountName").RefersToRange.Text & "_LD_Vertrag_DE.docx", FileFilter:="Word Files (*.docx), *.docx")
WordDocument.SaveAs2 (ExportPath)

ExcelExport = Replace(ExportPath, ".docx", ".xlsm")

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs (ExcelExport)
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

Comment: Does it also come up if you don't save the Word document (If you comment out the `WordDocument.SaveAs2` line)? Or try to save the Excel file as MacroEnabled `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ExcelExport FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`

Comment: @Peh Yes it happens with the commented out too. First one shows as Filetype "(*.docx)" and second shows Filetype "(*.xlsm")

Comment: Did you try to save the Excel file as MacroEnabled `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=ExcelExport FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled`?

Comment: Doesn't work either, same result as before..

Comment: Then you will have to show us a minimal example where it fails. I can't see any issues and the code works.